# google e-commerce tracking ID

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

i try to use this google e-commerce tracking code from google docs:

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});
```

and

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});
```

Now i wonder where I get the ID from?

-> Is it a free chose or do I get from google analytics?

-> If it's free chosen whats the best way to store it? Use a cookie?

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: I would think that transaction id would be the transaction id from your system.  One would think you save transaction data in your own database.

Comment: thanks for your replay, ok so i have to get the transaction id out of the database each time i add a item to the ecommerce object …

Comment: That would make it easier to relate numbers from your analytics system to your actual sales. But if you do not need that you can just as well pass in a random id.

Comment: But the id must be the same on every transaction?

Comment: The id must be unique per transaction, however with the standard e-commerce code it needs to be the same in the addTransaction call and the individual addItem calls  (since it ties the products to the transaction).

Comment: ok great, thanks for your answer!